# SqlAlchemy bulk upsert with unique `set_` values (Postgres)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to perform a bulk upsert with SqlAlchemy and Postgres in which all rows being upserted receive a ***unique set of values*** to update in the event there is a conflict.

I would prefer to do this ***without a for loop*** so that I'm only executing one SQL statement overall. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here's what I currently have. This method works as intended when using the `.on_update_do_nothing` method. I'm wondering how to properly pass each set of values so that each record is updated with the proper information in the event of a conflict instead of generic values. As far as I am aware, attempting `excluded` data as suggested in similar question answers will not solve this problem, as `set_` expects a dictionary of values, not a list.

```
def bulkUpsert(self, items, unique_fields):
  """
  Either inserts items into the table of supplied schema or does nothing.
  Requires items to be mapped prior to being passed to this method.
  """
  try:
    statement = postgresql \
      .insert(self.SCHEMA.__table__) \
      .values(items) \
      .on_conflict_do_update(
        index_elements = unique_fields,
        set_ = What to put here?
      )

    self.SESSION.execute(statement)
    self.SESSION.commit()

  except SQLAlchemyError as err:
    print("Error with bulk insert: %s" % (err))
```

Currently, the `items` parameter is a list of dictionaries, which will work as intended when